# Wikipedia article's semi-protection has expired, but it is still semi-protected

Tags: wikipedia

I thought the semi-protection status expires automatically, but I guess this is not so.  Who is responsible for enforcing that an article whose expiration date has passed for semi-protection is in fact taken off semi-protection?

Answer (score 1):

Semi-protections do expire automatically, but note that

- Administrators can change the expiration date at any time to any date
- Time zones may cause the time displayed to be different from your time (you can set your time zone in Special:Preferences)
- Your IP in particular may be banned from editing even after the protection expires.

Comment: you are 100% wrong.  the article in question's expiration date of semi-protection is 17:40, 16 May 2018 (UTC)))), which was yesterday.  so obviously they don't expire automatically, but have to be erased manually, which was obviously not done, as it is still semi-protected.

Comment: It would help if you linked to your article in question.

Comment: Yeah. Also note that the lock icon on the page saying its semi-protected can persist for longer than the actual protection sometimes.